# Setup SD Card on desktop computer to be ready tor the Pi

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I have been searching to see if it is possible to setup an SD Card on my desktop computer to be ready for the raspberry pi.

Things like setup a user, wifi, install initially required app (like docker + docker-swarm), etc... and have it ready for the pi so that I just need to power it up.

I have looked online into solutions with virtual machines, but there doesn't seem to be something like what I am looking for available. but would like to ask if anyone else can suggest a solution.

(alternatively, I will have to setup the pi's individually.... but this is not a fun process.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the the Rasperry Pi Imager utility from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/imager/imager.exe

You can then set up ssh and wifi by adding 
`f:\ssh` or `f:\ssh.txt` as an empty file and a `f:\wpa_supplicant.conf` with your WiFi credentials.

Comment: I do not understand the answer. On a desktop computer, how do you "*setup a user, wifi, install initially required app (like docker + docker-swarm), etc... and have it ready for the pi so that I just need to power it up*"?